FEP sticking to screen protector causing air bubbles below the protector
New to printing. Getting good prints with Anycubic Photon mono X2. After my last print I noticed an air bubble under the screen protector. When I pulled the vat out it sounded like it was stuck a little to the screen protector. Can you put something between the FEP and the screen protector to keep them from sticking together?
